# How to restrict access to docroot folder of glassfish server

Tags: .htaccess, glassfish

Inside the doc root of the glassfishserver I have created a `.htaccess` file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "aaa"
AuthUserFile "C:\Users\user01\Desktop\.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

And on the desktop I have created the `.htpasswd` file:

```
test:abcdefghnkfurfuhukrfknrnkrnkurf
```

But the glassfish server seems to ignore the `.htaccess` file. Anything else to do?

Comment: seems that .htaccess is not interpreted by glassfish. Did you find an alternative approach?

Comment: Not yet. But I don't longer use the glassfishserver.